# AWS which strategy is used scaling down instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Maybe this is a trivial question, but does anyone know which instance (oldest, newest, historically laziest) is taken out of rotation in AWS when the Auto Scaling is scaling down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Default Termination Policy**

When using the default termination policy, Auto Scaling selects an instance to terminate as follows:

1. Auto Scaling determines whether there are instances in multiple
   Availability Zones. If so, it selects the Availability Zone with the
   most instances and at least one instance that is not protected from
   scale in.
2. If there is more than one Availability Zone with this
   number of instances, Auto Scaling selects the Availability Zone with
   the instances that use the oldest launch configuration. Auto Scaling
   determines which unprotected instances in the selected Availability
   Zone use the oldest launch configuration. If there is one such
   instance, it terminates it.
3. If there are multiple instances that use the oldest launch
   configuration, Auto Scaling determines which unprotected instances
   are closest to the next billing hour. (This helps you maximize the
   use of your EC2 instances while minimizing the number of hours you
   are billed for Amazon EC2 usage.) If there is one such instance, Auto
   Scaling terminates it.
4. If there is more than one unprotected instance closest to the next
   billing hour, Auto Scaling selects one of these instances at random.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingBehavior.InstanceTermination.html